# Deploying heroku application - Internal Server Error

Tags: deployment, heroku

I am trying to deploy static webpage to Heroku and following this:
[official tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-on-heroku)

When I want to see my page in browser, I get the following error message:

```
Internal Server Error
No such file or directory - public/index.html
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09) at dosasite2013.herokuapp.com:80
```

My config.ru is as follows (based on official tutorial)

```
        use Rack::Static,
        :urls => ["/stylesheets", "/images"],
        :root => "public"

    run lambda { |env|
      [
          200,
          {
              'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
              'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
          },
          File.open('public/index.html',File::RDONLY)
      ]
    }
```

When I run the App internally via rackup...the public/index.html page appears ok...

[Here is my link to directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYtVl.jpg)

What to do to see my page at Heroku?

Comment: are the files in the repository that you push?

Comment: Yes, I used git add . ...[here is my command prompt](http://imgur.com/RqB01)

Answer (score 0):

It is solved.In config.ru file I changed `public/index.html` to `Public/index.html`, same with `:root => "Public".`

The reason is that my directory starts with capital P and not small 'p'.